# python, Json and string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, url, httplib2

I am using Python, and I sent a request to a URL and received a reply using httplib2. The reply I got was in JSon, how do I access a specific parameter. What I have at the moment is:

```
resp, content = parser.request(access_token_uri, method = 'POST', body = params, headers =     headers)
raise Exception(content['access_token'])
```

and I get the error

```
string indices must be integers, not str
```

How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well if the response type is json and it comes in type str.

If you are running 2.4 of Python use simplejson if 2.6 use json:

```
import json
# Your code
  retdict = json.loads(content)
```

Then treat it like a dictionary.

```
accesstoken = retdict['access_token']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dump;

```
result = json.dumps(content)

result = json.loads(result)
```